# Jenkins HTTP Request Plugin authorization error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, httprequest, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

So I am using Jenkins HTTP Requests plugin to do a POST method. I have specified the authorization and the apiKey in the header and the same is sent along with the request as headers. I am still getting a 401 unauthorized error. Anything that I might be missing?

This is the request made:

```
def response_POST = httpRequest httpMode: 'POST', acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', requestBody: payload, url: endpoint, customHeader: [[name: 'Authorization', value: 'apiToken <token>'], [name: 'apiUser', value: 'test'], [name: 'api_key', value: <value>]]
```

The following is the error:

```
Response Code: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: Verify you can success to send such request with by PostMan which is a chrome app, you can search and install it.  Or try by `curl` linux cmd

Comment: Thank you for the response, the postman request went through properly.
I was able to solve this by adding ```authentication``` parameter in my request. The value of the said parameter should be credentialID from the Jenkins Pipeline.